# Reading a file in Spark in cluster mode in Amazon EC2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I'm trying to execute a spark program in cluster mode in Amazon Ec2 using

```
spark-submit --master spark://<master-ip>:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --class com.mycompany.SimpleApp ./spark.jar
```

And the class has a line that tries to read a file:

```
JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile("/user/input/CHANGES.txt").cache();
```

I'm unable to read this txt file in cluster mode even if I'm able to read in standalone mode. In cluster mode, it's looking to read from hdfs. So I put the file in hdfs at /root/persistent-hdfs using

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /wordcount/input
hadoop fs -put /app/hadoop/tmp/input.txt /wordcount/input/input.txt
```

And I can see the file using `hadoop fs -ls /workcount/input`. But Spark is still unable to read the file. Any idea what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the following points:

- **Is the file really in the persistent HDFS?**

It seems that you just copy the input file from `/app/hadoop/tmp/input.txt` to `/wordcount/input/input.txt`, all in the node disk. I believe you misunderstand the functionality of the `hadoop` commands.

Instead, you should try putting the file explicitly in the persistent HDFS (`root/persistent-hdfs/`), and then loading it using the `hdfs://...` prefix.

- **Is the persistent HDFS server up?**

Please take a look [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Using-persistent-hdfs-on-spark-ec2-instanes-td790.html), it seems *Spark* only starts the ephemeral HDFS server by default. In order to switch to the persistent HDFS server, you must do the following:

- 1) Stop the ephemeral HDFS server: `/root/ephemeral-hdfs/bin/stop-dfs.sh`
- 2) Start the persistent HDFS server: `/root/persistent-hdfs/bin/start-dfs.sh`

Please try these things, I hope they can serve you well.